# How are sunglasses only reflective on one side?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, refraction

Sunglasses can be colored on one side, and dark on the other?  Why aren’t both sides either dark or both sides colored. I figured it worked like a one way mirror - but after holding both sides up to the sun I noticed only one side was still colored.

Comment: Sometimes there is a coating only on one side.

Answer (score 0):

Glass mirrors are coated with reflective metal (typically sputtered aluminum) on only one side of the glass sheet.